# Spree + Overwrite whole code base for modification and addition of new features

Tags: spree, overwrite, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Just beginner for Spree Framework

I am trying to bring the whole code base to my local repository, so that I am make relevant changes as per my requirement like addition of different API calls to fill by Product tables.

Just like Devise, we can bring the code base to local code base for modification. In the same manner, I am willing to pull the code base and making changes as per requirement.

Please suggest something so that I can make changes as per my requirement.

I found Solidus as option to full fill my requirement.

Thanks

Comment: You haven't asked a question here. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can just override/add code as you want using `class_eval`. Here is example

```
#app/controllers/spree/admin/images_controller_decorator.rb
Spree::Admin::ImagesController.class_eval do
  def index
    @images = Spree::Image.all
  end
end
```